# creating data frame from subsets and excluding data

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean-operations

These are the head()s of my two data frames (I have several of these but with different EXPANSIONs (bones):

```
                        CEMETERY CONTEXT    SEX EXPANSION VALUE
613     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 L   285
681     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7223   MALE    HuL1 L   310
860     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7314   MALE    HuL1 L   357
1301    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8102   MALE    HuL1 L   323
1441    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 L   316
1575    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 L   326
1655    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8268 FEMALE    HuL1 L   292
1902    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9362 FEMALE    HuL1 L   283
1932    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9373   MALE    HuL1 L   316
2368    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9813   MALE    HuL1 L   320
2947    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10145   MALE    HuL1 L   320
3033    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10218   MALE    HuL1 L   320
3062    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10241   MALE    HuL1 L   341
3159    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10420   MALE    HuL1 L   327
3294    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11005   MALE    HuL1 L   304
3471    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11090 FEMALE    HuL1 L   309
3723    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11494   MALE    HuL1 L   324
4128    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12356   MALE    HuL1 L   319
4206    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12414   MALE    HuL1 L   323
4344    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12493   MALE    HuL1 L   325
4421    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12520   MALE    HuL1 L   325
4470    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12525   MALE    HuL1 L   347
4837    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12761   MALE    HuL1 L   322
4948    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12785   MALE    HuL1 L   335
5072    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13530   MALE    HuL1 L   341
5317    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13747   MALE    HuL1 L   337
5840      Medieval-Spital Square      19 FEMALE    HuL1 L   326
5927      Medieval-Spital Square      22   MALE    HuL1 L   330
6044      Medieval-Spital Square      31   MALE    HuL1 L   328
6177      Medieval-Spital Square      95   MALE    HuL1 L   316
6336      Medieval-Spital Square     298   MALE    HuL1 L   347
6725      Medieval-Spital Square     349 FEMALE    HuL1 L   310
6827      Medieval-Spital Square     358   MALE    HuL1 L   336
6959      Medieval-Spital Square     383 FEMALE    HuL1 L   319
7105      Medieval-Spital Square     391   MALE    HuL1 L   352
7167      Medieval-Spital Square     394   MALE    HuL1 L   317
7322      Medieval-Spital Square     430   MALE    HuL1 L   318
7765 Medieval-St. Benet sherehog    1511 FEMALE    HuL1 L   296
7808 Medieval-St. Benet sherehog    1566   MALE    HuL1 L   314

                        CEMETERY CONTEXT    SEX EXPANSION VALUE
166     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    6225   MALE    HuL1 R   346
345     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    6351   MALE    HuL1 R   330
612     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 R   286
660     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7202   MALE    HuL1 R   340
1214    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8016   MALE    HuL1 R   334
1348    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8111 FEMALE    HuL1 R   308
1440    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 R   320
1574    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 R   326
2205    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9543   MALE    HuL1 R   326
2508    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9901   MALE    HuL1 R   354
2731    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    9987   MALE    HuL1 R   324
2778    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10058   MALE    HuL1 R   345
2832    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10070   MALE    HuL1 R   360
3032    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10218   MALE    HuL1 R   325
3061    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10241   MALE    HuL1 R   341
3236    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   10801   MALE    HuL1 R   344
3470    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11090 FEMALE    HuL1 R   312
3655    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11475   MALE    HuL1 R   339
3722    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   11494   MALE    HuL1 R   334
4205    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12414   MALE    HuL1 R   327
4298    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12480   MALE    HuL1 R   318
4343    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12493   MALE    HuL1 R   325
4420    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12520   MALE    HuL1 R   331
4469    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12525   MALE    HuL1 R   342
4947    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   12785   MALE    HuL1 R   338
5244    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13678   MALE    HuL1 R   342
5288    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13724 FEMALE    HuL1 R   319
5316    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13747   MALE    HuL1 R   340
5374    Medieval-St. Mary Graces   13825   MALE    HuL1 R   349
5839      Medieval-Spital Square      19 FEMALE    HuL1 R   332
5926      Medieval-Spital Square      22   MALE    HuL1 R   338
6043      Medieval-Spital Square      31   MALE    HuL1 R   328
6176      Medieval-Spital Square      95   MALE    HuL1 R   316
6245      Medieval-Spital Square     269   MALE    HuL1 R   339
6288      Medieval-Spital Square     287 FEMALE    HuL1 R   282
6335      Medieval-Spital Square     298   MALE    HuL1 R   352
6410      Medieval-Spital Square     309   MALE    HuL1 R   332
6724      Medieval-Spital Square     349 FEMALE    HuL1 R   313
6826      Medieval-Spital Square     358   MALE    HuL1 R   340
6958      Medieval-Spital Square     383 FEMALE    HuL1 R   322
7104      Medieval-Spital Square     391   MALE    HuL1 R   355
7166      Medieval-Spital Square     394   MALE    HuL1 R   322
7321      Medieval-Spital Square     430   MALE    HuL1 R   325
7404      Medieval-Spital Square     472   MALE    HuL1 R   346
7502 Medieval-St. Benet sherehog      67   MALE    HuL1 R   339
```

I need to exclude any CONTEXTs (specimens) that do not have both the left (L) and (R) measurement of a bone. I have made subsets of just the CONTEXTs for these data frames

```
HuL1L.id=HuL1L$CONTEXT
HuL1R.id=HuL1R$CONTEXT
```

and intended to use the boolean operator %in% to find out which individuals in one of the vectors is also in the other

```
HuL1L.id%in%HuL1Rframe.id

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[11] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[21]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[31]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

but I'm unsure what to do beyond this point - as in how to actually create a data frame with this data, looking like this:

```
                         CEMETERY CONTEXT    SEX EXPANSION VALUE
613     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 L   285
612     Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 R   286
1441    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 L   316
1440    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 R   320
1575    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 L   326
1574    Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 R   326
```

and then repeat this for my other bones, and finally combine all of these data frames.

EDIT:

using:

```
HuL1R <- HuL1R %>% filter(CONTEXT %in% Hul1L$CONTEXT)
HuL1L <- HuL1L %>% filter(CONTEXT %in% Hul1R$CONTEXT)
Full_HuL <- bind_rows(HuL1R, HuL1L) %>% arrange(CONTEXT, EXPANSION)
```

still gives me CONTEXTs which only have either HuL1 L or HuL1 R

```
                      CEMETERY CONTEXT    SEX EXPANSION VALUE
1       Medieval-Spital Square      19 FEMALE    HuL1 L   326
2       Medieval-Spital Square      19 FEMALE    HuL1 R   332
3       Medieval-Spital Square      22   MALE    HuL1 L   330
4       Medieval-Spital Square      22   MALE    HuL1 R   338
5       Medieval-Spital Square      31   MALE    HuL1 L   328
6       Medieval-Spital Square      31   MALE    HuL1 R   328
7  Medieval-St. Benet sherehog      67   MALE    HuL1 R   339
8       Medieval-Spital Square      95   MALE    HuL1 L   316
9       Medieval-Spital Square      95   MALE    HuL1 R   316
10      Medieval-Spital Square     269   MALE    HuL1 R   339
11      Medieval-Spital Square     287 FEMALE    HuL1 R   282
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is `group_by` and `filter` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Full <- bind_rows(HuL1L, HuL1R) %>%
    group_by(CONTEXT) %>%
    filter(any(EXPANSION == "HuL1 L"),
           any(EXPANSION == "HuL1 R")) %>%
    arrange(CONTEXT, EXPANSION) %>%
    spread(EXPANSION, VALUE)
```

If you want to reshape, you can use `library(tidyr)`

Comment: I tried all 3 of these, but my data frame still includes specimens with only 1 bone measurement, I'm not sure why this would be

Comment: can you use `dput(head(50))` on both dataframes and post the outputs so I can play around with it? I need some reproducible code to see what your error is.

Comment: I've put in my entire data frames now

Comment: I just tried my first answer, and it worked. So I'm not sure why it isn't for you, try my last answer using `group_by`, or if you could post more details as to why it isn't working or if there is something else you're trying to do. My first answer does yield your expected output, identically.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to `rbind` your data frame and use the `duplicated` function in base r

```
 dat3=rbind(dat1,dat2)
 dat4=dat3[duplicated(dat3$CONTEXT,fromLast = T)|duplicated(dat3$CONTEXT),]
 dat4[order(dat4$CONTEXT),]
                         CEMETERY CONTEXT    SEX EXPANSION VALUE
 1  613  Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 L   285
 9  612  Medieval-St. Mary Graces    7172 FEMALE    HuL1 R   286
 5  1441 Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 L   316
 13 1440 Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8117 FEMALE    HuL1 R   320
 6  1575 Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 L   326
 14 1574 Medieval-St. Mary Graces    8207   MALE    HuL1 R   326
```

using the pipe:

```
 rbind(dat1,dat2)%>%{.[duplicated(.[2])|duplicated(.[2],fromLast = T),]}%>%{.[order(.[2]),]}
```

data used:

```
 structure(list(CEMETERY = c("613  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "681  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", "860  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "1301 Medieval-St. Mary Graces", "1441 Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "1575 Medieval-St. Mary Graces"), CONTEXT = c(7172L, 7223L, 7314L, 
  8102L, 8117L, 8207L), SEX = c("FEMALE", "MALE", "MALE", "MALE", 
 "FEMALE", "MALE"), EXPANSION = c("HuL1 L", "HuL1 L", "HuL1 L", 
 "HuL1 L", "HuL1 L", "HuL1 L"), VALUE = c(285L, 310L, 357L, 323L, 
 316L, 326L)), .Names = c("CEMETERY", "CONTEXT", "SEX", "EXPANSION", 
 "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

 dat2=structure(list(CEMETERY = c("166  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "345  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", "612  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "660  Medieval-St. Mary Graces", "1214 Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "1348 Medieval-St. Mary Graces", "1440 Medieval-St. Mary Graces", 
 "1574 Medieval-St. Mary Graces"), CONTEXT = c(6225L, 6351L, 7172L, 
 7202L, 8016L, 8111L, 8117L, 8207L), SEX = c("MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", 
 "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE", "MALE"), EXPANSION = c("HuL1 R", 
 "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R", "HuL1 R"
 ), VALUE = c(346L, 330L, 286L, 340L, 334L, 308L, 320L, 326L)), .Names = c  ("CEMETERY", 
 "CONTEXT", "SEX", "EXPANSION", "VALUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -8L))
```

Comment: I know you're not supposed to just comment thanks but I have to say thank you so much, I have been struggling with this for days and it has finally worked! would you also know how to then make a new column that only includes the right measurements, whilst the other only contains left measurements?

Comment: Sure just reshape your data!

Comment: If this question did answer your problem, then please accept it to close down this question. Also you can upvote the question

Comment: you can use `tidyr::spread(data, key=EXPANSION, value=CONTEXT)` for example to reshape your data, or you can use `reshape2::dcast(data,CONTEXT~EXPANSION)` an so many more functions you can even use the `reshape()` in base R.